# How to learn current class of div element on debug

Tags: javascript

I am debugging my javascript code on Google Chrome, and when it stops on the breakpoint I want to learn the current class name of the div with id "loadingElement". With the javascript code I try to change its class as loaded/loading. But I am not sure if it changes.

What should I write down to the console to see its current state?

This is what div looks like:

```
<div id="loadingElement" class="loaded">
```

Comment: what are you using to change the class?

Comment: Can't you just see the class change in the DOM with the dev tools?

Comment: Typing document.getElementById('loadingElement') into the console should do the trick.  But as per above - use "Elements" to inspect the element in real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are trying to do:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('loadingElement').className);
```

I hope you're trying to remove that element after that is loaded, if so use like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('loadingElement');
if(el.className == 'loaded'){
   el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('loadingElement');
console.log(elem);
```

Answer (score 0):

**IF** the class change happened, you will see it in the DOM in chrome. It is updated real time.

You can also get the element via Javascript and print it out in the console:

```
var el = document.getElementById('loadingElement');
console.log(el);
```

Or directly print the class list:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('loadingElement').classList);
```

`Classlist` will print all classes, as opposed to `className`, that will print one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in Chrome dev tools you can use some of the useful [console functions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#selecting-elements):

```
console.log($('#loadingElement').className)
```

Here `$()` is a shortcut for `document.querySelector` (do not confuse with jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

You have a few possibilities:

```
document.getElementById("loadingElement").className
```

Or, you can type:

```
 document.getElementById("loadingElement")
```

And in your console the following appears and you can already see its attributes.
[image]

If you need it, right clicking on it and selecting "Reveal in Elements panel", allows you to see it on the DOM:
[image]

If you need to know this inside an animation, it could be helpful to type:

```
setInterval(function(){
     console.log(document.getElementById("loadingElement").className)
}, 100);
```

In this way, every 100ms the className will be printed on the console